# facebook open graph: objects not updated

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

This an example of my object:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# openfever: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/openfever#">

 <meta property="fb:app_id"                      content="260740230708137" /> 
 <meta property="og:type"                        content="openfever:plan" /> 
 <meta property="og:url"                         content="http://app.feverup.com/openFever/index.html" /> 
 <meta property="og:title"                       content="Sutton Club" /> 
 <meta property="og:image"                       content="http://www.gettyimages.es/images/marketing/frontdoorStill/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" /> 
 <meta property="openfever:precio"               content="18€" /> 
 <meta property="openfever:fevers_dentro"        content="12" /> 
 <meta property="openfever:porcentaje_de_chicas" content="60%" /> 
 <meta property="openfever:price" content="40€" />
```

And this is the code that publish the action:

```
FB.api(
                '/me/openfever:getin',
                'post',
                { 
                    plan: 'http://app.xxx.com/openxxx/index.html',
                    //place: 'suttonoficial', 
                    place: 'Opiummar',
                    tags: '728885016',
                },
                function(response) {
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                      console.log(response.error);

                   } else {
                      console.log(response.id);
                   }
        });
```

The action and object is published. But I have a problem. How i can publish different objects? It means, changing the price, the image..

If i change some property of the object, the object is not updated. But if i user object debugger all published objects are updated. Not only one.

My question: It's possible to publish multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

> How i can publish different objects?

By providing the data under a *different* URL …

Open Graph objects basically just *are* URLs. So if you want to have multiple objects, set up multiple URLs and have them each deliver an HTML document with appropriate OG meta tags set.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I only have one object called "plan". Each plan have an image, a price, etc.. The structure of the object doesn't change, only change the proprieties. How i can publish the same object with different proprieties? Now, when I change one propriety the object is not updated. On the other side, if I user object debugger all objects are updated.

Comment: _“How i can publish the same object with different proprieties?”_ – by __not__ publishing the same object, but a different one – using a _different URL_. _“On the other side, if I user object debugger all objects are updated.”_ – of course, if all of these objects are represented by the same URL, which makes them just _one_ object.